# Data not being set before rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var DialogController = function ($scope, configFac, $q) {
    var placeholders = [];
    var varInit = function () {
        $q.all([configFac]).then(function (response) {
            $scope.configResources = response[0];
            placeholders[0] = response[0].one;
            placeholders[1] = response[0].two;
            placeholders[2] = response[0].three;
        });
    };

    var states = {
      'initial': {
        'key': 'initial',
        'inputPlaceholder': placeholders[0],
        'avatar': {
          'state': 'default'
        }
      },
      'editing': {
        'key': 'editing',
        'inputPlaceholder': placeholders[1],
        'avatar': {
          'state': 'listening'
        }
      },
      'answered': {
        'key': 'answered',
        'inputPlaceholder': placeholders[2],
        'avatar': {
          'state': 'thinking-complete'
        }
      }
     };
)};
```

So when I run this code with my project, the inputplaceholders are being set as nothing because the promise isn't returning quick enough. Is there a way to make it wait? Also, another way to fix this, there is intro code run in the beginning of the project, so is there a way to make a call from a different module to make this run while that code is running?

Answer (score 0):

Set new values to your states object in the promise `then`:

```
var DialogController = function ($scope, configFac, $q) {
    var placeholders = [];
    var varInit = function () {
        $q.all([configFac]).then(function (response) {
            $scope.configResources = response[0];
            placeholders[0] = response[0].one;
            placeholders[1] = response[0].two;
            placeholders[2] = response[0].three;

            states.initial.inputPlaceholder = placeholders[0];
            states.editing.inputPlaceholder = placeholders[1];
            states.answered.inputPlaceholder = placeholders[2];
        });
    };

    var states = {
      'initial': {
        'key': 'initial',
        'avatar': {
          'state': 'default'
        }
      },
      'editing': {
        'key': 'editing',
        'avatar': {
          'state': 'listening'
        }
      },
      'answered': {
        'key': 'answered',
        'avatar': {
          'state': 'thinking-complete'
        }
      }
     };
)};
```

Comment: Is `varInit` actually called ?

Comment: It is but after the states variable

Comment: What do you need states for ? Maybe set it as a `$scope` prop if you need it in your view ?

Comment: It is used for different functions within the controller, so it has to be a var